SQL Server table names in a combobox VFP
How to store SQL Server table names in a combobox in VFP?
After I read on VFP ComboBox Content from SQL Server 2005 Express table
Can someone help me to store table names from SQL Server to a combobox in VFP?
I tried with sqltables() and store in Grid1 VFP that can show name table is.
My code on load form:
public KONEKSI, mskedul1 
STORE SQLCONNECT('surya','surya','surya_database') TO KONEKSI 
IF KONEKSI > 0 
    SQLEXEC(KONEKSI,'use ksp_arthasurya') 
endif 
SQLTables(m.KONEKSI,'TABLE','tableList')

My code on init form:
thisform.grid1.recordsource = 'tablelist'

and on my grid1 shown table that contain on my SQL Server dbo.ksp_arthasurya
My question is: I want the names of all tables that belong to the dbo.ksp_arthasurya schema shown in my combobox in VFP. If I click on a name in the VFP combobox, my grid1 in VFP should show the data in that table.

thanks.. for editting my question, in here iam newbie.

(You are asking the same question on multiple sites, aren't you reading the replies? Anyway)
Here is a sample form that would get the table names into a combobox and upon selection of a table, show that table's top 100 rows in a grid:
(Note that since a combobox with style 2 is something that user cannot type, this code wouldn't be treated it as prone to SQL injection attack - but in your real use case you should thoroughly make that assessment)
Public oForm
oForm = Createobject('SampleForm')
oForm.Show()


Define Class SampleForm As Form
    Height=800
    Width =600

    Add Object cmbTables As ComboBox With Left=10, Top=10, Width=300,Style=2
    Add Object grdViewer As Grid With Left=0,Top=40,Height=760,Width=600,Anchor=15

    Procedure Init
        Local KONEKSI, lcSQL
        STORE SQLCONNECT('surya','surya','surya_database') TO KONEKSI 
        * Store Sqlstringconnect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=...;Database=ksp_arthasurya;...') To m.KONEKSI
        IF m.KONEKSI < 0 
            MESSAGEBOX("Couldn't connect.",0,'SQL Server connection',5000)
            RETURN .F.
        endif 
        SQLEXEC(m.KONEKSI,'use ksp_arthasurya')

        This.AddProperty('nHandle', m.KONEKSI)

        TEXT TO m.lcSQL noshow
Select CAST(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(Name) as varchar(200)) AS TableName
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE is_ms_shipped=0
ORDER by schema_name(schema_id), Name
        ENDTEXT

        lnResult    = SQLExec(m.KONEKSI, m.lcSQL,'TableList')
        If m.lnResult < 0
            Aerror(aWhy)
            Messagebox(aWhy[2])
            SQLDisconnect(0)
            Return .F.
        Else
            With Thisform.cmbTables
                .RowSourceType = 3
                .RowSource = 'select TableName from TableList into cursor crsTables nofilter'
                .ListIndex=0
            Endwith
        Endif
    Endproc

    Procedure cmbTables.InteractiveChange
        Local lcSQL

        Use In (Select('crsResult'))

        TEXT TO m.lcSQL TEXTMERGE noshow
select top(100) * from << TRIM(crsTables.TableName) >>
        ENDTEXT

        SQLExec(Thisform.nHandle, m.lcSQL ,'crsResult')
        With Thisform.grdViewer
            .ColumnCount = -1
            .RecordSource = "crsResult"
            .AutoFit()
        Endwith
    ENDPROC
    
    PROCEDURE Destroy
        SQLDISCONNECT(this.nHandle)
    endproc
Enddefine


@albharons did this answer your question?

@DaleK, it did. He continued to ask other questions on another forum.

the answer is in line with what I expected..

@albharons he meant why don't you mark it as answer :)
